# Multithreaded Directory Create

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have a function that is invoked by a thread trying to create a directory if its not created already. However FileAlreadyExistsException is thrown constantly when threads try to invoke this method in parallel. Making this method `synchronized` solves the problem but is there a better way. What is the right way to create directory or skip if directory is already created in a multi-threaded environment?

```
public void createDir(Path path){
    if (Files.notExists(path)) {
          Files.createDirectory(path);
    }       
}
```

Comment: How slow exactly?  I'd expect creating a file is much slower than synchronizing, which is relatively fast in most cases.

Comment: Oh by slow i meant only one thread would be able to enter this method.. Is there any better way to do it without synchronized? Modified the question too...

Comment: You can always synchronize code blocks instead of the whole method.  Synchronization is kind of *the* way of handling this sort of thing.  (sounds like in this case the VM already did the work for you though)

Comment: If you don't want to synchronize in any way just catch the exception and return from the method if another thread was faster and has created the directory already.

Comment: Moral of the story. Never look for a "better way" unless you *know* the current situation is (strongly) sub-optimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)), the "checking and create" function is already coded in `Files.createDirectory()` **and** is atomic (i.e. it's thread safe):

> The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the directory if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the directory.

So you should just be able to remove the extra existence check:

```
public void createDir(Path path){
      Files.createDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: And what if the last name is actually a file instead of a folder (or, if you are running windows crap FS, `NUL` or `LPT1`)?

Comment: Yes you'll get FileAlreadyExistsException. Although I guess I read the question as the ops is controlling what's being created and the multi-threading aspect of it is what's causing the collisions, not some uncontrolled external code writing in that same area.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I'd still catch / upgrade the exception of course. We can leave the exception handling out for the sake of brevity I guess.

Comment: @mprivat: Actually createDir method is the method called by all threads to check if a directory exists and create it if it doesn't exist already.. So yes FileAlreadyExistsException is still thrown. Is there any other method that does nothing without throwing exception?

Comment: In this particular case, I'd probably catch the specific FileAlreadyExistsException and silence it within the method. Assuming you are completely in control of the directory content (i.e. the multi threads is what's causing the conflict, not some other process coming to play in your sandbox)